# export certain worksheets using a userform

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform, export-to-pdf

I would like to make exports based on the boxes I checked

therefore with a lot of help I build the following code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim xSht As Worksheet, xFileDlg As FileDialog, xFolder As String, xYesorNo, I, xNum As Integer
 Dim xOutlookObj As Object, xEmailObj As Object, xUsedRng As Range, xArrShetts As Variant
 Dim xPDFNameAddress As String, xStr As String, rngExp As Range, lastRng As Range
 
 xArrShetts = sheetsArr(Me) 'do not forget the keep the sheetsArr function...

 For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
    If xSht.Name <> xArrShetts(I) Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet no found, exit operation:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & xArrShetts(I), vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
    End If
 Next

 Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
    xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
 Else
    MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
    Exit Sub
 End If
 'Check if file already exist
 xYesorNo = MsgBox("If same name files exist in the destination folder, number suffix will be added to the file name automatically to distinguish the duplicates" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Click Yes to continue, click No to cancel", _
 vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
 If xYesorNo <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
 For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
    Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
    
    xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & ".pdf"
    xNum = 1
    While Not (Dir(xStr, vbDirectory) = vbNullString)
        xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & "_" & xNum & ".pdf"
        xNum = xNum + 1
    Wend
    Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
        Set lastRng = xSht.Range("A" & xSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)   'determine the last cell in A:A
        Set rngExp = xSht.Range(lastRng.Offset(-26), lastRng.Offset(, 7))  'create the range to be exported as pdf
        With xSht.PageSetup
              .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
              .PrintArea = rngExp.Address(0, 0)
              .Orientation = xlLandscape
              .FitToPagesWide = 1
              .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With
        rngExp.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xStr, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IgnorePrintAreas:=False  'export the range, not the sheet
    End If
    xArrShetts(I) = xStr
 Next

 'Create Outlook email
 Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
 With xEmailObj
    .Display
    .To = ""
    .cc = ""
    .Subject = "????"
    For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
        .Attachments.Add xArrShetts(I)
    Next
    If .DisplayEmail = False Then
        '.Send
    End If
 End With
End Sub

Private Function sheetsArr(uF As UserForm) As Variant
  Dim c As MSForms.Control, strCBX As String, arrSh
      For Each c In uF.Controls
            If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
                If c.Value = True Then strCBX = strCBX & "," & c.Caption
            End If
      Next
      sheetsArr = Split(Mid(strCBX, 2), ",") 'Mid(strCBX, 2) eliminates the first string character (",")
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Unload basicUserform

End Sub
```

the problem is when I run the code no attachments show up or can be found in the destination map I choose earlier.

I also put the file here so you can see for yourself.:
https://easyupload.io/ufnmvr

I appreciate your help and time!

Comment: You need to cancel that `On Error Resume Next` using `On Error Goto 0` as soon as it's no longer needed, or you will not see any errors in your code...

Comment: hello, CDP1802, thanks for your reply! I tried your solution but got a error "sub of Function is not defined".

Comment: @CDP1802, did you experience the same??

Answer (score 0):

Added a check for valid range of 27 or more rows otherwise `lastRng.Offset(-26)` will fail and because `On Error Resume Next` was not cancelled with `On Error Goto 0` it won't raise an error.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim xSht As Worksheet, xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xFolder As String, xYesorNo, I, xNum As Integer
    Dim xOutlookObj As Object, xEmailObj As Object
    Dim xUsedRng As Range, xArrShetts As Variant
    Dim xPDFNameAddress As String, xStr As String
    Dim rngExp As Range, lastRng As Range
     
    xArrShetts = sheetsArr(Me) 'do not forget the keep the sheetsArr function...
    If UBound(xArrShetts) < 0 Then
        MsgBox "No sheets selected", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' check sheets exist
    For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
         On Error Resume Next
         Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
         If xSht.Name <> xArrShetts(I) Then
             MsgBox "Worksheet no found, exit operation:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                    xArrShetts(I), vbInformation
             Exit Sub
         End If
         On Error GoTo 0
    Next

    Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
        xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check if filename already exist
    xYesorNo = MsgBox("If same name files exist in the destination folder," & _
                      "number suffix will be added to the file name automatically " & _
                      "to distinguish the duplicates " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                      "Click Yes to continue, click No to cancel", _
                      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
    If xYesorNo <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

    For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
        Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
        
        xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & ".pdf"
        xNum = 1
        While Not (Dir(xStr, vbDirectory) = vbNullString)
            xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & "_" & xNum & ".pdf"
            xNum = xNum + 1
        Wend
        Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
            'determine the last cell in A:A
            Set lastRng = xSht.Range("A" & xSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            If lastRng.Row < 27 Then
                MsgBox "Incorrect Start Row " & lastRng.Row, _
                       vbCritical, "ERROR on " & xSht.Name
                Exit Sub
            End If
            'create the range to be exported as pdf
            Set rngExp = xSht.Range(lastRng.Offset(-26), lastRng.Offset(, 7))
            With xSht.PageSetup
                .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
                .PrintArea = rngExp.Address(0, 0)
                .Orientation = xlLandscape
                .FitToPagesWide = 1
                .FitToPagesTall = 1
            End With
            'export the range, not the sheet
            rngExp.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xStr, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
            xArrShetts(I) = xStr
        Else
            ' no file created
            xArrShetts(I) = ""
        End If
    Next

    'Create Outlook email
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .To = ""
        .cc = ""
        .Subject = "????"
        For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
            If Len(xArrShetts(I)) > 0 Then
                .Attachments.Add xArrShetts(I)
            End If
        Next
        .Display ' or ' Send
    End With
End Sub
```